# Unable to change main scene

Tags: godot, gdscript

Very new to this: I am trying to switch my main scene in project settings from World.tscn to Menu.tscn but I am met with this warning.

[image: Warning]

The Menu.tscn works fine and the project is not running while I am trying to change the main scene. No clue why this does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Godot will even let you change that while the game is running. The problem must be external. Do you have the project open with some other editor (or perhaps is there some other software with the file open)? You could try sysinternals procexp to find what software it is (using the find handle option). I guess some antimalware could do that too. It probably goes away with a reboot, but if that is the case, you won't know what it was. If it persists, worst case it is a disk problem. If that is the case make a copy of the project and work on the copy. And, hey, backups? version control?

Comment: Hi thanks for the tips! Tried working from a copy then did a reboot but the problem persists. Hopefully I'll figure it out soon.

Comment: If there is a process messing with the files even after the reboot, it has to be something that starts with the system. You can try looking for something suspicious on sysinternals autoruns. On the other hand, if it is a disk issue, hopefully it can be fixed by the scan that windows offers from the properties of the volume, or with chkdsk from command line.